# Use Viewpager with NavigationDrawer leads to Blank page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, android-adapter

When click the items of NavigationDrawer,The main activity container switch the fragments to show,It worked fine until I met this:

1.Switched to FragmentA, which CONTAINS A VIEWPAGER,it showed well.

2.Switched to fragmentB,fragmentB showed well.

**3.Swiched back to
   FragmentA,it shows as a Blank View**

I tried to flip horizontally on it,I can see the viewpager index do changed(in log),But I don't know why it showed as a blank page.
*and,if fragmentA dose not contains viewpager,it worked well

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I use replace() to switch between the fragments:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, currentFragment)
                .commit();
```

Comment: There's really nothing we can tell you without seeing some code.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason might be not using `replace` transaction instead you mightbe adding fragments and adding it to backstack. Try using replace transaction, and see if it works.

```
Fragment1 firstFragment = new Fragment1();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
firstFragment.setArguments(bundle);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.article_fragment, firstFragment)
.commit();
```

Learn More on Fragments adding to back stack:
[Android Fragment transaction: FragmentManager and Backstack](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-transaction-fragmentmanager-and-backstack.html)

Comment: Thank you.I'm sorry for not post my code ealier,I used replace().But I'll try  adding fragments your menthioned and see if it works.